# LyX Japanese input

Tags: lyx

I've been using LyX for a while now, but for the life of me I have been unable to find a way to input Japanese into my documents. This is particularly frustrating as I recently need to publish documents with both English and Japanese.

I'm currently running OS X El Capitan, and the LyX help page is of no assistance as the main link for Japanese LyX input (OS X) is broken. 
https://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/Japanese

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please give more details? What do you mean by "unable"? What happens when you try to input Japanese? Nothing? Or do you get an error? Or you cannot compile? LyX has manuals (Help > ...) and example files written in Japanese.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Yes, I probably should have been a bit more specific. I am able to input Japanese, however I am unable to compile and output a PDF with both English and Japanese.

Comment: Can you compile the Japanese help documents? Which version of LyX are you using?

Comment: Really appreciate your help scottkosty.

No, I can't compile the Japanese help documents, even if I set my default language to Japanese. I'm using LyX 2.1.4 

I'm guessing there's a LaTeX patch/package or something I need to install in order for LyX to compile Japanese characters?

Comment: I just tested and on 2.1.4 I can compile the Japanese manuals with both PDF (ps2pdf) and PDF (dvipdfm). Both of these formats are available from the View Other Formats button. I don't know much at all about OS X or Windows. If you happen to have access to Ubuntu I can try to help, otherwise hopefully an OS X user comes along. I would suggest you do the following: Open the Japanese splash.lyx (this is in the examples folder in ja/splash.lyx). If you cannot compile this, go to File > Export > LaTeX (pLaTeX); make a simple example out of it.

Comment: Then post that simple example .tex file and also the log file you get when you run the command `platex` on that .tex file on tex.stackexchange.com.